# Books recommendations

Tags: discussion

Are questions about security books recommendations accepted ?

For example [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94961/books-about-theoretical-basis-in-log-management) is accepted and upvoted twice for the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, book recommendation both fall under these two "out-of-topic questions" categories:

- They are similar to **product recommendation**, as they become obsolete relatively quickly,
- They request **people opinion**, instead of "*facts, references, or specific expertise*", as the [Help page](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) states: "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page*". There is no way to tell what could be *the right answer* to such a question as "Could you recommend some books?".

Comment: Yes, I feel you are right. Thank you.